# Lock Text to Bottom of Browser HTML / CSS

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

I need to lock a div with text to the bottom of the browser window.

Basically need to create a footer bar that scrolls normally with the browser but always stays at the exact bottom of the browser window

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use fixed positioning:

```css
#bottom-bar {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

for example. [Here's a demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/minitech/5Wypu/)